# Can I programmatically detect whether a CORB error occurred?

Tags: javascript, chromium, detection, cross-origin-read-blocking

I'm looking for a way to programmatically detect (using JavaScript) whether a resource load on my page (over which I have full control) was blocked by [Cross-Origin Resource Blocking](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/site-isolation#corb).

For instance, because the response from `https://example.com` has Content-Type `text/html; charset=UTF-8`, the following HTML code would trigger a CORB error in Chromium-based browsers:

```html
<script src="https://example.com"></script>
```

But how can I detect that it occurred? Simply adding a handler for the `error` event on the script element isn't working; for instance, the following code doesn't open a dialog box:

```html
<script src="https://example.com" onerror="alert('CORB!')"></script>
```

Note that I'm *not* interested in *fixing* the CORB error or *inspecting* the contents of the CORB error; I'm only interested in detecting programmatically whether a CORB error occurred. Is that even possible?

Comment: Do you really need to say it was because of CORB or is just the error enough? BTW, that seems like a Chrome bug there is no error on script. They do fire it on img: https://jsfiddle.net/31y2dmt9/

Comment: @Kaiido Sorry for not getting back to you earlier, I was researching the topic myself. It's not a Chrome bug that there is no error on script, because Chrome removes the body of the response, and an empty response is valid JS. It fires for an image because an empty response is not a valid image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm happy to be proven wrong but, according to what I've read so far, programmatically detecting whether a CORB error occurred is impossible, at least in general.

However, in some cases, you may be able to leak some information cross-origin:

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) is a web platform security feature aimed at reducing the impact of speculative side-channel attacks such as Spectre.
> Unfortunately, blocking certain types of requests introduced a new type of XS-Leaks that allows attackers to detect if CORB was enforced on one request, but wasn’t on another.

(source: https://xsleaks.dev/docs/attacks/browser-features/corb/)

Comment: https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/727 still open, but I think it os the way it will go.